# AngularJS Function call looses object scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a URL with query params as below.

http://somehost/page.html#/?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Inside the JS file I have a controller which defines a function as per the below code and makes a http call and assignes the data to the $scope.

```
angular.module('ngApp').controller('Cntrl', function ($scope,$location,$http){
    var val1 = $location.search()['param1'];

    $http.get('/api/call').success(function(data) {
         $scope.empList = data; 
         console.log ($scope.empList) ; // return data 
    });

    console.log ($scope.empList) ; // return undefined when accessed with above url 
    $scope.fetch = function() {
     // some code  which uses $scope.empList here 
    }

    $scope.fetch(); 
}
```

I have just started to learn angularJS and no idea why `$scope.empList` is undefined outside the http block.

Comment: `$http.get()` is asynchronous so your object is probably not populated by the time `$scope.fetch()` is called. Why don't you perform any additional logic inside your success function in `$http.get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP request is asynchronous. So you need to do like this:

```
angular.module('ui.kpi.bugs').controller('BugKpiForm', function ($scope,$location,$http){
var val1 = $location.search()['param1'];

$scope.empList = [];

$http.get('/api/call').success(function(data) {
     $scope.empList = data; 
     console.log ($scope.empList) ; // return data 

     $scope.fetch(); // invoke only when empList data is available.
});

$scope.fetch = function() {
 // some code  which uses $scope.empList here 
}
```

Comment: This isn't seem to work as I need to use $scope.empList inside $scope.fetch.

Comment: $scope.fetch = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.empList.length; i++) {
            var emp1 = $scope.fetch[i];
            if(emp1.key = "empName") {
                console.log("Name Exists")
            }
        }
}

Comment: I've edited the answer. I guess, you have to set init value for `$scope.empList = []` to make it works. And you have an error inside your loop: `$scope.empList[i]` instead of `$scope.fetch[i]`

Comment: Thanks alot Sir , It works very well. Truly appreciated.